# custom form module not showing upload functionality

Tags: 7, forms

```
<?php

function form_test_menu() {
  $items['formtest'] = array(
    'title' => 'Form Test',
     'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
     'page arguments' => array('form_test_form'),
     'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
   return $items;
}    

function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) {
   $form['firstname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Firstname'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
    $form['lastname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Lastname'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    );
  return $form;
}
```

Hello all,

Can anyone explain to me why this will not work?  I am trying to test the form submission and I created a module folder with a .info file.  I am using mywebiste/formtest, but every time I try and load the page it says "page not found."  I have been looking at tutorials and they all seem to work fine but it seems that I must be doing something wrong.  Any thoughts?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: really sorry, I forgot to update the title, I was going to ask a different question but decided not to in the end.  Sorry!

Comment: what is your module name?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear all cache of your Drupal website and try to access your url: http://wwww.your_domain.com/formtest

Comment: Hello Dvex,
I have cleared the cache every time I update code and still no luck.

Comment: Hello Aboodred my module name is upload

Comment: Drupal hook implementations are always the module (or theme) name replacing the word "hook".

So `form_test_menu()` is the **form_test** module's implementation of `hook_menu()`.

If your module name is, as you say, **upload**, then you should name your functions as `upload_menu()`, etc.

Comment: @pjcdawkins I Agree with you. Replace the word HOOK with the name of your module.